# How to make the text stay in the text box when app is reopened using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just wondering how exactly I could make tkinter save the text in the current window so that when the app is closed and reopened, it would still be there. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to write code to save the data to a file or database, and then load the data when the app starts.

Comment: @BryanOakley That was my thought, but I'm unsure how to go about that. Will try again though, thanks.

Comment: I used this import configparser

Answer (score 0):

```
# save the data - in this case '1234', converted to a string
# the value must be a string!
with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(1234))

# load the data from the file
with open('save.txt', 'r') as f:
    load = f.read()
    print(load)
```

This is a *very* barebones example and will only store one value in the file
at a time since every call to `f.write()` will overwrite the existing file!

If you're looking for something a little more robust but still easy to implement, try the `configparser` module - it lets you read/write `*.cfg`/`*.ini` files, which are great if all you need are key-value relationships!